# Displaying repeating table from SharePoint list

Tags: infopath

I'm trying to retrieve a repeating table through data connection from SharePoint list. I have a drop down that has project names. Depending on which project I choose, the financial details should be retrieved from that particular project in SharePoint list and displayed in my form.

If the repeating table has five rows, I need all the five rows to be displayed. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please tell me how do i establish data connection to my repeating table? Should I use edit defaul values from properties option?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already added a data connection to both your Drop Down list (e.g. showing all available projects in a list) and the Repeating table.

This being in place, you need to select your repeating table, go to the properties of the Data Source and while selecting let's say one field on the table and you have the Filter button in the lower part of your window. Use that define the relationship between between the actual value in the drop down.

I believe this link should give you step-by-step walkthrough http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/videos/cascading-dropdown-lists-infopath-repeating-table.htm